# Get Days from a Calendar using JSOM

Tags: calendar, jsom, sharepoint-calendar

I'm developing a form to add weekly timesheets for employees. I need to get days from a calendar using JSOM to display on the form on the form load. I need to display the current week on the form by default and users should be able to navigate to next week and previous week using the buttons on each side. Also I need to display each day relevant to the selected week separately to add project information.

[image]

What would be the best approach to achieve this functionality? Can I use SharePoint calendar to do this? Or should I create my own list with this date information manually to get this data? Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I'd use your own list, the only reason you'd need a calendar is if you want a calendar view, even then there are plenty of javascript plugins and angular directives that can achieve this using a CEWP to surface.

Comment: @Mike But my client insist on this exact design. So I'll have to stick to this design of the form. Seems like my only option is to use my own list to get this date information. Thanks.